Does PHP Mailer work with tls port 587 over a https connection and with a AWS elastic beanstalk deployment?
I have a PHP web application I am trying to deploy via AWS elastic beanstalk.  I noticed that PHP Mailer sends email when it is sent over a http connection using port 587 and tls but it hangs when you try to send email over a https connection and port 587 and tls?  I was wondering if anyone has had this issue and how it can be fixed?
This is the function in my code:
    function sendEmail($name, $email,$subject, $body, $altBody)
{
    try
    {
      $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
      $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
      $mail->Encoding = 'base64';

      //Set PHPMailer to use SMTP.
      $mail->isSMTP();
      $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;

      //Set SMTP host name
      $mail->Host = $_SERVER['smtp_server'];

      //Set this to true if SMTP host requires authentication to send email
      $mail->SMTPAuth = true;

      //Provide username and password
      $mail->Username = $_SERVER['smtp_username'];
      $mail->Password = $_SERVER['smtp_password'];

      //If SMTP requires TLS encryption then set it
      $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';

      //Set TCP port to connect to
      $mail->Port = 587;

      $mail->From = $_SERVER['no_reply_email'];
      $mail->FromName = $_SERVER['fromName'];

      $mail->addAddress($email, $name);
      $mail->isHTML(true);
      $mail->Subject = $subject;


      $mail->Body = $body;
      $mail->AltBody = $altBody;
      $mail->send();

      return true;
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
      echo $mail->ErrorInfo;
      return false;
    }
}


Not sure what you mean by HTTP vs HTTPS. There's no HTTP here, it's SMTP.

What information do you get from the PHPMailer debug log?

I mean when your application is running on https://example.com vs http://example.com.  It sends the email via SMTP when you run the application on http://example.com but not when you run the application on https://example.com.  When I submit the form which calls the function to send the email, when it is sent over a http connection the email is sent but when I submit the form which triggers the send email function over a https connection, I get a 504 Gateway timeout error.

I also do not get anything from PHP Mailer.  I just get a 504 Gateway Timeout error.

If the result differs between http:// and https:// then SMTP has literally nothing to do with it. It doesn't even have anything to do with PHP, it's a web server config issue.
